# Taking Portions of a String

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I am working on an assignment which is confusing to me. It requires me to write a method called processName() that accepts a Scanner for the console as a parameter and prompts the user to enter a full name, then prints the last name first and then the first name last. For instance, if I enter "Sammy Jankins",  it would return "Jankins, Sammy".

My plan is to go through the string with a for loop, find an empty space, and create two new strings out of it—one for the first and last name each. However, I am not sure if this is the right path and how to exactly do this. Any tips would be appreciated, thanks.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Exercise15 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    processName(inputScanner);

}

public static void processName(Scanner inputScanner) {

    System.out.print("Please enter your full name: ");
    String name = inputScanner.next(); 
    System.out.println();

    int n = name.length();
    String tempFirst;

    for (int i = 0; i <= name.length()-1; i++) {
        // Something that checks the indiviual characters of each string to see of " "exists
        // Somethow split that String into two others.  
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Please check the various helper methods for Strings like split() etc

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)?

I won't solve this for you, but here what you should do:

1. [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) according to spaces.
2. Check if the size of the array is 2.
3. If so, print the second element then the first.

Tip: Viewing the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) can save a lot of efforts and time.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just to say:

```
String[] parts = name.split("\\s+");
String formattedName = parts[1] + ", " + parts[0];
```

I am leaving it for you as an exercise to support names that contain more than 2 words, for example "Juan Antonio Samaranch" that should be formatted as "Samaranch, Juan Antonio".

Answer (score 0):

Using [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) will be more easier. Refer http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/ for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace for loop with the following code:

```
int spaceIdx = name.indexOf(' '); // or .lastIndexOf(' ')
if (spaceIdx != -1) {
    int nameLength = name.length();
    System.out.println(name.substring(spaceIdx + 1) + ", " + name.substring(0, spaceIdx));
} else {
    // handle incorrect input
}
```

I think you should also consider such inputs - Homer J Simpson

Answer (score 0):

1.Use the StringTokenizer to split the string .This will be very helpful when you are trying to split the string.

```
String arr[]=new String[2]; int i=0; StringTokenizer str=new StringTokenizer(StringToBeSplited,"");
while(str.hasMoreTokens()){ 
    arr[i++]=new String(str.nextToken());
}
System.out.println(arr[1]+" "+arr[0]);
```

That's all